# How to use python boto3 library for connecting to private s3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I need to connect to s3 and see if the test1.txt file is already present. If present, ignore and if not present, upload to s3. This is a inhouse s3 for which I have the details as below. I have been unable to even connect successfully to s3. I am new to python and any help will be greatly appreciated. thank you!

```
import boto3
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

accessKeyId = 'abc'
secretKey = 'xyz'
host = 'ecscloudstorage.asd.com'
port = 8080
signatureVersion = 's3'
accountType = 'S3 Compatible Storage'
bucketName ='testsomething'
# fileName = 'C:\\test1.txt'

conn = S3Connection(aws_access_key_id=accessKeyId,
                aws_secret_access_key=secretKey,
                host=host,
                port=port,
                is_secure=False)

print(conn.get_all_buckets())

my_bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucketName)
# print(my_bucket.name)
```

Comment: What is the error message you're getting back? Also, be aware None is the python equivalent of null - "None" is a string - if you're trying to pass the null equivalent, remove the quotes.

Comment: Did you setup the "inhouse S3"? Does anybody else have working code that uses it? What code is it running on (that is, was it built in-house, or was it downloaded from somewhere)?

Comment: I just updated the code snippet. Now i am able to get a list of all buckets. but i get below error on line "my_bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucketName)" :   File "C:\Users\smita\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\socket.py", line 914, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

Comment: just to add on the above error - I tries this code separately "import socket
socket.getaddrinfo('ecscloudstorage1.medassurant.local', 8080)" and its worked fine with no errors. cant figure out whats different with conn.get_bucket ?